# Delphi: BASS.dll - how to copy part of MP3 stream to another file

Tags: delphi, mp3, bass, bass.dll

Im using BASS.dll library and all I want to do is to "redirect" part of MP3 Im playing using for example BASS_StreamCreateFile to another file (may be MP3 or WAVe). I dont know how to start? Im trying to use help to find an answer, but still nothing. I can play this stream. Read some data I need. Now I need to copy ile for example from 2:00 to 2:10 (or by position).
Any ideas how should I start?

Regards,
J.K.

Comment: 1) Seek to the correct position. 2) Copy the data into a buffer. 3) Create an output file. 4) Copy the buffer into the output file.  Which part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: I dont want to hard-copy part of file. I want to copy part of MP3 into another MP3. I cannot just copy for example X bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know BASS specifically, but I know a little about music playing and compressed data formats in general, and copying the data around properly involves an intermediate decoding step.  Here's what you'll need to do:

1. Open the file and find the correct position.
2. Decode the audio into an in-memory buffer.  The size of your buffer should be `(LengthInSeconds * SamplesPerSecond * Channels * BytesPerSample)` bytes.  So if it's 10 seconds of CD quality audio, that's 10 * 44100 * 2 (stereo) * 2 (16-bit audio) = 1764000 bytes.
3. Take this buffer of decoded data and feed it into an MP3 encoding function, and save the resulting MP3 to a file.

If BASS has functions for decoding to an external buffer and for encoding a buffer to MP3, you're good; all you have to do is figure out which ones to use.  If not, you'll have to find another library for MP3 encoding and decoding.

Also, watch out for [generational loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).  MP3 uses lossy compression, so if you decompress and recompress the data multiple times, it'll hurt the sound quality.

Comment: Thats a good point, thanks. Ill try it and Ill also try to find another library for this. And Ill let you know - if it works Ill accept this answer.